# iOS Twitter website single sign on

Tags: ios, twitter, uiwebview, twitter-oauth

Say that you have an iOS app, and a user that has one or more Twitter accounts set up on their device. Is it possible to load part of Twitter's mobile site into a `UIWebView` within the app *with the user automatically signed in* as one of those accounts?

Obviously, accessing the accounts would require the user's permission, which is fine. And probably after the first time, the site would remember the user anyway. But it would be nice to not force the user to enter their credentials again.

I know that I can use [Reverse Auth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) to get OAuth tokens for an iOS Twitter account, but I haven't found anything concrete to allow me to exchange those tokens for authentication on twitter.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to [Twitter's Taylor Singletary](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14247), it's not possible. Boo.